# How to prevent emailed cron output

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I'm using a cron that gets accesses a URL to run a scheduled process.  I keep getting successful emails... is there a way for me to only get emails if the wget request fails?

wget http://www.domain.com/cron/dailyEmail 2>&1;

Comment: wget -q http://www.domain.com/cron/dailyEmail; if you want no output at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wget --quiet http://www.domain.com/cron/dailyEmail || echo "wget failed"
```

(Note that an empty response is not a failure.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running wget directly in the cron setup, then no. You can't conditionally redirect output. You could, however, put the wget command into a shell script, and do the conditionals there.

```
#!/bin/sh

OUTPUT=`wget .... 2>1`
if [ $? != 0 ]
   echo $OUTPUT
fi
```