# Stopping cron output

Tags: php, cron, wget

I have a cron command below that is sending me status outputs on the wget.... I really don't want these outputs, I just want the code to run.

```
wget http://www.domain.com/cron/dailyEmail 2>&1;
```

How can I turn off the output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent emailed cron output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246850/how-to-prevent-emailed-cron-output)

Comment: Actually I originally thought that was a dupe (and unfortunately voted to close) but there's a subtle distinction. While the other one wanted notification on failure, this one doesn't seem to care - it doesn't want to see any output at all.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that, but there are a number of answers to that question which answer this question so it seemed kinda pointless.

Comment: To close as a dupe, the _question_ should be a dupe. If you close questions because a _different_ question has an answer, that breaks the SO searchability. Classic example was a question I asked on how to do something with `awk`. One answer was how to do it in `R` - I don't know why, it seems bizarre to me - I'm not installing and learning `R` just so I can do my work :-) Especially in a locked down corporate environment. Now, if someone asks how to do it in `R`, you don't want to close that as a dupe since anyone searching for an `R` solution is going to ignore `awk` questions as irrelevant.

Comment: @paxdiablo I see your point, but I saw the question earlier, and I know the answers there will answer this question, so I dunno why he was asking again. I'll follow that advice for next time though, thx.

Comment: i use the --delete-after and -q switch on wget

Comment: you can use --quiet to turn off wget's output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send the output to the **null device**.

`wget http://www.domain.com/cron/dailyEmail >/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

Send it to a temporary file thus:

```
wget http://www.domain.com/cron/dailyEmail >/tmp/my_wget.out 2>&1
```

That way, you can see the output if you need to but it doesn't otherwise bother you.

If you want to keep older copies of the output around rather than over-writing them on each run, you can use something like:

```
wget http://www.domain.com/cron/dailyEmail >/tmp/my_wget_$(date +%Y_%m_%d).out 2>&1
```

which will give you a filename containing the date (and time if you change the arguments to the `date` command) but then you'll probably want an automated process to clean up older log files.